# Regression Tables in R Markdown / rmarkdown (html/pdf)

Tags: r, r-markdown, stargazer, texreg

For the purpose of publishing I often need both a PDF and a HTML version of my work including regression tables and I want to use R Markdown. For PDF the `stargazer` and the `texreg` packages produce wonderful tables. Now trying to generate an equally attractive HTML output I'm facing different issues.

1. <strike>Both methods for HTML output are **lacking significance stars** in the notes. As they are automatically generated I don't know how to escape them. (I think this might be a minor problem and therefore I didn't want to split it into seperate questions.)</strike> ***Note:*** Sub-question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44473379/how-to-show-significance-stars-in-r-markdown-html-output-notes).
2. Before creating the definite output I often have to change my data or do some formatting. I find it quite annoying to always flip-flop the options between `type='html'` to `type='pdf'`manually. I wonder if there might be a more feasible way to **combine the html/pdf output** , e.g. a case-to-case switch in `texreg` / `stargazer` with a tidy output?

I tried the promising [`pander`-solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342162/regression-tables-in-markdown-format-for-flexible-use-in-r-markdown-v2), but it seems not to be working anymore since 2014. Also [`pixiedust`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147756/exporting-r-regression-summary-for-publishable-paper/30149717#30149717) ist not very satisfying, it's becoming somewhat manual at the end and not exactly what I want. [An other example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19997242/simple-manual-rmarkdown-tables-that-look-good-in-html-pdf-and-docx) seems to refer only to normal tables.

Any help is extremely appreciated, thanks!

Here is a summary of my attempts for `knitr` in HTML and PDF:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
```{r table, results = "asis"}
library(car)
lm1 <- lm(prestige ~ income + education, data=Duncan)

## html
# stargazer
library(stargazer)
stargazer(lm1, type="html", notes="stargazer html")
# htmlreg
library(texreg)
htmlreg(lm1, custom.note="%stars. htmlreg")

## pdf/latex
# stargazer
stargazer(lm1, notes="stargazer latex")
# texreg
texreg::texreg(list(lm1), custom.note="%stars. texreg")

# pixiedust
library(pixiedust)
dust(lm1, caption = "pixiedust")

# pander
library(memisc)
library(pander)
lm1_table <- mtable(lm1)
# pander(lm1_table, style="rmarkdown") # not working
pander(lm1)
```
````

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35149103/4132844 ; you could set `type` in stargazer depending on the output format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a proposition: make a function that checks the output format and then uses either stargazer or texreg depending on this. We use `opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to")` to check the output format.

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
rmd_format <- opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to")
## returns "html" or "latex"

```

```{r}

report_regression <- function(model, format, ...){
  if(format == "html"){
    require(texreg)
    htmlreg(model, custom.note="%stars. htmlreg", ...)
  } else if(format == "latex"){
    require(stargazer)
    stargazer(model, notes="stargazer html", ...)
  } else {
   print("This only works with latex and html output") 
  }
}
```

```{r table, results = "asis"}
library(car)
lm1 <- lm(prestige ~ income + education, data=Duncan)

report_regression(lm1, format = rmd_format)
```
````

Comment: Awsome, thx!! I'm pretty excited that customization even works using the function in chunks: `lm1 <- lm(prestige ~ income + education, data=Duncan); lm2 <- lm(prestige ~ income + education + income:education, data=Duncan); report_regression(list(lm1, lm2), format = rmd_format, custom.model.names = c("West", "East"), custom.coef.names = c("(C. 1)", "I. 1", "E. 1", "Inter. 1"), custom.note = "%stars. foo", star.symbol = "&#42;")` I suggest to change `lm1` to `model` in function and rather use `texreg` than `stargazer` 'cause it's more sophisticated. `stargazer` still best choice for the console.

Comment: ``rmd_format <- opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to")`` was just what the doctor ordered!  You can pass ``type = rmd_format`` directly to ``stargazer()``  without the need for a function, as far as I could tell in my limited experience.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out [in an answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48458182/), `knitr` 1.18 [introduced](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/NEWS.md#changes-in-knitr-version-118) the following functions

```
knitr::is_html_output()
knitr::is_latex_output()
```

to check if the output is HTML or LaTeX. Adapting @scoa's excellent answer:

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r}

report_regression <- function(model, ...){
  if(knitr::is_html_output()){
    require(texreg)
    htmlreg(model, custom.note="%stars. htmlreg", ...)
  } else if(knitr::is_latex_output()){
    require(stargazer)
    stargazer(model, notes="stargazer html", ...)
  } else {
   print("This only works with latex and html output") 
  }
}
```

```{r table, results = "asis"}
library(car)
lm1 <- lm(prestige ~ income + education, data=Duncan)

report_regression(lm1)
```
````